# Expanding selenium2 functionality PageFactory

Tags: c#, reflection, selenium-webdriver, castle-dynamicproxy

I want to add a  functionality to selenium2 `PageFactory`. What I want is that `FindsByAttribute` was compatible with `SelectedElement`.
The problem that I discovered that if I'm adding property with `SelectElement` type into `IWrapsElement` and implementing it in `ProxiedWebElementInterceptor`. When method `SetValue` of the filed is called he says " Object of type 'Castle.Proxies.INewsWrapsElementProxy' cannot be converted to type 'OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.SelectElement'."
Could some one explain castle proxy's mechanism that returns needed value?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
// Presumed to be in Page class
[FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "ButtonId")]
public IWebElement submitButton { get; set; }

// Presumed to be in Helpers class
public void ScrollToElementOnPage(IWrapsElement element) 
{ 
   var js = driver as IJavaScriptExecutor;
return  js.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);",element.WrappedElement);
}

Helpers _helpers = new Helpers();
Page _page = new Page();
_helpers.ScrollToElementOnPage((IWrapsElement)_page.submitButton);
```